# Host WCF service through console app

Tags: .net, wcf

This is probably an easy solution.

I have created the simplest WCF host in a project like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
           typeof(AmphoraService.ConsignmentService.Consignment)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Consignment Service Activated! Press <Enter> to terminate " +
               "the Host application.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I have supplied the configuration in the app.config file.

When pressing F5 in Visual Studio it runs successfully. The text is displayed in the console window and "netstat -a" shows that port 808 is listening (its a nettcp binding)

However, when I exit Visual Studio and try to click on the bin\debug***.exe file, a console window appears but nothing happens! And "netstat -a" shows that port 808 is NOT listening.

What am i overlooking?

Comment: after the `Console.ReadLine()`, it's better to `host.Close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing happens, its likely that the program is sitting on the `host.Open()` line. Try attatching visual studio to that instance (using Debug > attatch to process).

You can also try waiting a little while and see if you get an exception such as a timeout or something, its possible that something is going wrong when the ServiceHost is trying to instansiate your service object

Perhaps some resource gets locked when you run it the first time (in visual studio)? what if you reboot and run the exe from explorer first?

Comment: hmm.. actually i was a little too fast here. It seems that when enabling the visual studio hosting process (....vshost.exe) the service starts up lightning fast. But when disabling this, it takes about 2 minutes to start up. Strange..

Comment: hm ok, try setting breakpoints in the constructor for your service class and see how long it takes to reach them. what transport are you using btw?

Comment: I'm using nettcp binding. dude, it works now, the startup time does not concern me. I give you the cred for trying to solve my problem. thanks